# NullPointerException destroying AdView

Tags: android, adview

I'm creating my AdView like this in onPostCreate:

```
 private AdView mAd;

 public void onPostCreate(Activity a) {
     LOGE(TAG, "Ads are enabled: creating");
     mAd = (AdView) (a.findViewById(R.id.adView));
     AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
     adRequest.addTestDevice("xxxxxx");
     mAd.loadAd(new AdRequest());
 }
```

I'm then destroying it like this:

```
public void onDestroy(Activity a) {
    if (mAd != null) {
         mAd.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

From my users logs I can see sometimes:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.webkit.WebView.requestFocus(WebView.java:8925) ... at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:2135) ... at
>   org.akul.psy.gui.BaseActivity.onDestroy(BaseActivity.java:69)

I believe this is because there's some problem with me destroying my AdView.

Do I do that correctly? Do I have to do that at all? I'm destroying it because I've followed Google example (I believe).

Comment: which line is the 69th line of `BaseActivity` class?

Comment: please post all logcat error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to destroy the adView only if you have created the AdView instance in code like this

AdView adView = new AdView(this);

but in your case your Adview is in your xml, and your trying to find the instance of the view ( not a new memory allocation). The instance created in xml will be destroyed when the activity is removed from stack.